# Create new folder and upload files to custom folder via wp_handle_upload

Tags: php, plugin-development

I am using `wp_handle_upload` to upload files from a theme template file.

```
if ( ! function_exists('wp_handle_upload') ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['attachedfile'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    //echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    //var_dump( $movefile);
     $attachedfilelink=$movefile['url'];
}
```

I want to create a folder inside root / uploads directory with user name of who is uploading  and upload the file inside the folder.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a working example but should help,

Use `wp_upload_dir()` to define the default  *uploads* folder and append a username to it using `wp_get_current_user`.

```
$wp_upload_dir =  wp_upload_dir();
$user_folder = wp_get_current_user();

// The actual folder
$custom_upload_folder= $wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . $user_folder->display_name;
//make the dir
mkdir($custom_upload_folder);
```

You would need to employ security and code that checks for errors/user capabilities and sets the correct file/folder permissions. Also have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API which employs `mkdir`.